# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException in POM uisng page Factory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I've posted below some sample code which I've done so far and I'm getting an Exception `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

**Base Class:**

```
public class TestBase {
    public static WebDriver driver= null;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void initialize(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","...chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("abcd.com");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void TearDownTest()
    {
        TestBase.driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Login Page:**

```
public class LoginPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver= driver;
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='email_id']") WebElement EmailTextBox;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='password']")WebElement PassworTextBox;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='frm_login']/div[4]/input") WebElement LoginButton;

    public void setemail(String strmail)
    {
        EmailTextBox.sendKeys(strmail);
    }

    public void setpwd(String strpwd)
    {
        try
        {
            PassworTextBox.sendKeys(strpwd);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Time out exception " + e);
        } 
        catch (ElementNotSelectableException e) {
            System.out.println("Element not selectable exception " + e);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("No such element found " + e);
        } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something Wrong " + e);
        }
    }

    public void ClickLoginBtn()
    {
        LoginButton.click();
    }
}
```

**LoginTest class:**

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase{

    @Test
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("In the init method");
        LoginPage lg=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        lg.setpwd("123123");
        lg.setemail("abc@gmail.com");
        lg.ClickLoginBtn();
    }
}
```

I am getting the `NullPointerException` while setting the username and password. Could you please help me?

I am new to the POM with PageFactory so I dont have any idea How to resolve it but If anyone can help me with that it would be big help to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't initialise the *WebDriver* instance i.e. **`driver`** twice as follows:

```
public static WebDriver driver= null;
```

and

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Keep the global declaration as:

```
public static WebDriver driver= null;
```

And channge the line as:

```
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a timeout after `driver.get("abcd.com");` to be sure page has finished to load, and can find WebElements defining EmailTextBox and PassworTextBox.
Or use a WebDriverWait like this

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.id("someid")));
```

Comment: An explicit wait is not going to fix a NullPointerException

Comment: If the problem comes from an undefined element due to absence of their id in page, it could be

Comment: @Ehcnalb No, that would throw `NoSuchElementException`. `NullPointerException` might be thrown if you didn't use `initElements` method of `PageFactory` class

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have initialized the page factory elements like so

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {           
  this.driver = driver; 
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

In your Test class,
I would place

LoginPage lg = new LoginPage(driver);

```
Read more here:
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver
```